# Propel "AND NOT" query

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I'm using the propel ORM in my PHP application.

From reading the docs, I can't figure how to make a request of this type:

```
SELECT x FROM table where col1 = 'xxx' and not(col2=1 AND col3=2);
```

What is the cleanest way to perform this request using pure propel logic?

Thanks

Comment: Logically, that's equivalent to col1 = 'xxx' AND (col2 != 1 OR col3 != 2)... which seems like it might be easier to express with `->combine(array('cond2', 'cond3'), 'or',...)`, then combine that with condition 1, `and`.  I can't be any more helpful, since I'm a DBA... so ORMs are my mortal enemy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that way earlier , using combine() but I faced a strange behavior: 

->condition('cond1', 'x != ?', 1) 
->condition('cond2', 'y != ?', 2)       
->condition('cond3', 'z != ?', 3)   
->combine(array('cond1', 'cond2',  'cond3'), 'or', 'cond12')  

results:

SELECT ... AND((x!=1 OR y!=2)OR z!=3)

Which is not really the same thing..

Comment: Woops, had an idiotic moment I guess, in fact, it's totally the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT x FROM table where col1 = 'xxx' and (col2 != 1 OR col3 != 2);
```

Assuming you are using propel 2, you should be able to accomplish what you'd like with:

```
$result = TableQuery::create()
    ->filterByCol1('xxx')
    ->filterByCol2(1, Criteria:NOT_EQUAL)
    ->_or()
    ->filterByCol3(2, Criteria:NOT_EQUAL)
    ->find();
```

Answer (score 3):

The complete query you're looking for should be this one:

```
$books = TableQuery::create()
    ->condition('cond1', 'col1 = ?', 'xxx')
    ->condition('cond2', 'col2 != ?', 1)
    ->condition('cond3', 'col3 != ?', 2)
    ->combine(array('cond2', 'cond3'), 'or', 'cond23')
    ->where(array('cond1', 'cond23'), 'and')
    ->find();
```

It creates:

- a **cond1** condition where *col1 = 'xxx'*
- a **cond2** condition where *col2 != 1*
- a **cond3** condition where *col3 != 2*

Then it combines *cond2* and *cond3* with a *or* operator in a new **cond23**, so that

```
cond23 = cond2 or cond3
```

and combines *cond23* and *cond1* with a *and* operator, so that the final query will be

```
where(cond1 and cond23)
```